# Is there any way to find the five character ID of the micro:bit in micropython?

Tags: bbc-microbit

This is how we get the device name using blocks

[image]

But I need to find the way to code in micropython to find the same.

I have tried the following:

```py
from microbit import *
while True:
    basic.show_string(control.device_name())
```

But this throws an error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

micropython for the micro:bit is different from the code used in the MakeCode editor.

They are both based on Hardware Abstraction Layer defined at the following location:
https://lancaster-university.github.io/microbit-docs/concepts/

The documentation for micropython is available at:
https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.1/microbit_micropython_api.html

There is not a unique name in the same way that there is in blocks.